# Angular, Calling a function with ng-click work only once with ng-route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I add a ng-click inside a ng-repeat, i want to get the single item in the loop, it work well but only once.

```
ng-repeat="item in Playlist.item" ng-click="getSingleItem(item)"
```

in my controller

$scope.getSingleItem = function (item) { 
    console.log(item);
  }

If i click i get the item object in my console log, this click is a href and send me to the next page with ng-route.
But if i go back and click the same link or another link, it won't work.

it fire only once.

UPDATE!
i just find out that with my own href directive and the ng-click it work only once, but if i just add a $timeout in my own directive it will work.

Comment: IT SHOULD BE: ng-repeat="item in Playlist.item" ng-click="getSingleItem(item)"

Comment: I know, it's just a copy pas error on stackoverflow. i find out that it work with my own directive and the ng-click stop functionning, but it work if i just add a $timeout in my directive.

Comment: @Gino you should post your answer, if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have posted the correct code, your ng-click should be placed outside ng-repeat,

```
ng-repeat="item in Playlist.item" ng-click="getSingleItem(item)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML code. You're missing a comma in that line.
This should be:

`ng-repeat="item in Playlist.item" ng-click="getSingleItem(item)"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing after the ng-repeat since your post doesn't have any other code, but I am guessing it is because you are not listing out the items you have in the ng-repeat.

I've done something like this which has worked:

```
<div>
     <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Item</td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody ng-repeat="item in Playlist.item" ng-click="getSignleItem(item)">
            <tr> 
               <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

You should now be able to do click on the item listed in the table which then executes the ng-click passing the clicked item.

Cheers!